# Do I need to replace my laptop's HDD? (GSmartControl analysis)

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, smart, diagnostic

I've got an ASUS laptop that is 5 years old already, never had a problem with it. After some weeks with it being not as responsive as usual, yesterday I formatted and repartitioned the HDD, and gave the laptop blasts of compressed air to remove any dust inside it. While I was installing the Windows 7's SP2, I heard a soft clicking coming from the hard drive, some hours later tried to reproduce the sounds by copying large amounts of files but was unable to do so. I know that sound usually means trouble, so I got a hold on GSmartControl. Ran a test and I see some indicators that say "pre-fail". I really have no knowledge of SMART jargon and such, but, should I worry? Here's what GSmartControl said about my hard drive:

```
smartctl 5.43 2012-06-30 r3573 [i686-w64-mingw32-win7(64)-sp1] (sf-5.43-1)
Copyright (C) 2002-12 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Western Digital Scorpio Black
Device Model:     WDC WD5000BEKT-80KA9T0
Serial Number:    WD-WXA1A70E6491
LU WWN Device Id: 5 0014ee 2afb01002
Firmware Version: 01.01A01
User Capacity:    500.107.862.016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   8
ATA Standard is:  Exact ATA specification draft version not indicated
Local Time is:    Mon Feb 29 21:29:49 2016 HPS
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 9960) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 118) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x7035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   178   174   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       2083
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5257
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       17463
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       5238
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       607
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       122
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   138   138   000    Old_age   Always       -       187648
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   106   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       41
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0

Read SMART Log Directory failed.

Error SMART Error Log Read failed: CSMI(25) failed with Error=31
Smartctl: SMART Error Log Read Failed
Error SMART Error Self-Test Log Read failed: CSMI(25) failed with Error=31
Smartctl: SMART Self Test Log Read Failed
Error SMART Read Selective Self-Test Log failed: CSMI(25) failed with Error=31
Smartctl: SMART Selective Self Test Log Read Failed
```

I already have a full backup, but I don't really want to run into any surprises. Do I need to replace my laptop's HDD, based on what GSmartControl says? Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I've never liked the idea of using compressed air to clean devices, as all it really does is push the dust around to other places, where it potentially could be more harmful. I think it's preferable to use a vacuum cleaner, as this removes the dust properly.

If your laptop is that old, upgrading the hard drive would be a very good idea. If you install an SSD, it will be much better than it was when it was new.

Comment: While it is true that air dusting just *"push the dust around to other places"*, generally pushing it away from sensitive electronics is a good thing...